The selected elements of some properties in a form are empty
In symfony 6.4 using ODM, I have a document that includes these properties
#[MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument: Collection::class, mappedBy: 'parent')]
 private DoctrineCollection $subCollections;

#[MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument: MediaFile::class)]
 private DoctrineCollection $mediaFiles;

I have created a form, with two fields
->add('mediaFiles', ChoiceType::class, [
 'label' => 'Media files',
 'choices' => $mediaFiles,
 'placeholder' => 'Select media files',
 'choice_label' => fn ($mediaFile) => $mediaFile instanceof MediaFile ? $mediaFile->getTitle() : '',
 'choice_value' => fn ($mediaFile) => $mediaFile instanceof MediaFile ? $mediaFile->getId() : '',
 'multiple' => true,
 'expanded' => false,
])

and
->add('subCollections', ChoiceType::class, [
 'label' => 'Subcollections',
 'choices' => $subCollections,
 'placeholder' => 'Select subcollection',
 'choice_label' => fn ($collection) => $collection instanceof Collection ? $collection->getTitle() : '',
 'choice_value' => fn ($collection) => $collection instanceof Collection ? $collection->getId() : '',
 'multiple' => true,
 'expanded' => false,
]);

In addition to these transformers
<?php

namespace App\Form\DataTransformer;

use App\Document\MediaFile;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class MediaFilesToIdsTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
 /**
 * Transforms a collection of MediaFile objects to an array of IDs.
 */
 public function transform($mediaFiles): array
 {
 if (!$mediaFiles instanceof Collection) {
 return [];
 }

 return $mediaFiles->map(fn (MediaFile $mediaFile) => $mediaFile->getId())->toArray();
 }

 /**
 * Transforms an array of IDs to a collection of MediaFile objects.
 */
 public function reverseTransform($mediaFilesIds): Collection
 {
 $mediaFiles = new ArrayCollection();

 foreach ($mediaFilesIds as $mediaFile) {
 $mediaFiles->add($mediaFile);
 }

 return $mediaFiles;
 }
}

and
<?php

namespace App\Form\DataTransformer;

use App\Document\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection as DoctrineCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class SubCollectionsToIdsTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
 /**
 * Transforms a collection of Collection objects (subcollections) to an array of IDs.
 */
 public function transform($subCollections): array
 {
 if (!$subCollections instanceof DoctrineCollection) {
 return [];
 }

 return $subCollections->map(fn(Collection $subCollection) => $subCollection->getId())->toArray();
 }

 /**
 * Transforms an array of IDs to a collection of Collection objects.
 */
 public function reverseTransform($subCollectionsIds): DoctrineCollection
 {
 $subCollections = new ArrayCollection();

 foreach ($subCollectionsIds as $subCollection) {
 $subCollections->add($subCollection);
 }

 return $subCollections;
 }
}

In the templates in the edition the values ​​of mediaFiles and subCollections are empty arrays
{{ dump(form.mediaFiles.vars.value) }}
{{ dump(form.subCollections.vars.value) }}

There is also a third property called tags that by verifying its content {{ dump(form.tags.vars.value) }} I get the expected values
The result of this is that the selected values ​​of the mediaFiles and subCollections properties are not shown in the form
